# Как составить правильный http запрос

Tags: java

Для скачивания файла по http(s) устанавливаю связь так:

```
URL connection = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection urlconn;
long size;

urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection.openConnection();
urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
size = urlconn.getContentLengthLong();
urlconn.connect();

InputStream in = null;

try {
    in = urlconn.getInputStream();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Обычно всё работает хорошо, но на некоторых файлах получаю:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://filecdn.to/fsuaget/Y2VkNTFjOTNkN2UzMDk5NmIyMzljMDBmOGZlZWFmZmJmc3RvfDE2MDQyMDI5MzN8MTAwMDB8MHwwfHw3MDU4MDIzZGEzNDQ4NDI5MTZhN2RiNGI4ZGYxMWNlZHwxfDE0Njg3NTM3NTF8dmlkZW8,/The.Walking.Dead.S06E01.1080p.HDTV.FOX
>   HD.ts

Если этот URL вставить в адресную строку браузера(Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m) файл скачивается нормально.
Насколько я понимаю, Chrome формирует правильный запрос, я - нет. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Если такая ошибка не всегда, то, видимо, дело в сервере. А браузер просто при ошибке повторяет запрос до тех пор пока он не увенчается успехом. Сделайте и вы так же

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал 10000 запросов подряд(~10 секунд долбил сервер) - ответ один и тот же

Comment: Попробуйте заменить пробелы в URL на `%20`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, точно) Оказалось Chrome так и делает

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оформите в виде ответа, пожалуйста

Comment: В подобных ситуациях можно использовать [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) для сравнения запросов от браузера и от вашего приложения.

Comment: @Dmitry, когда задавал вопрос, как раз хотел чтобы что-то такое посоветовали. Но вышло даже лучше, ув. ЮрийСПб помог решить проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в том, что тогда как браузер автоматически преобразует пробелы в URL в `%20`, у вас это не происходит. Засим вам надо вручную это сделать - заменить все пробелы в URL на `%20`

Comment: Оказывается, ссылка, которую я получаю в Exception и ссылка, которую я вводил отличаются. Похоже, происходит редирект. Получается, тот URL, которым отвечает сервер содержит пробел и т.д. и достать его я могу только прочитав `.getMessage()` Exception'a. Неужели так и делать?(

Comment: @DimTeam, попробуйте переписать чрез либу OkHttp - там можно настроить `redirect` - возможно это поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Cимволы, отличные от печатных **ANSI**, записываются в формате %NN, где NN - это шестнадцатиричный код символа. К примеру, пробел будет записан как **%20**, а символ % - как %25 ( смотрите [ASCII & ANSI Character Codes](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/java_http_web/codes.html)). Русские кириллические символы не входят в набор печатных ANSI символов, то в HTTP заголовках они тоже заменяются подобным образом.
Используйте `URLEncoder.encode(url,"utf-8")`. Он преобразует все символы которые не входят в ANSI в %   и шестнадцатеричный код символа. Это удобно и не нужно руками вставлять или заменять пробел.

Comment: Вот во что превращает `URLEncoder.encode(url,"utf-8")` приведённую в вопросе сылку: `http%3A%2F%2Ffilecdn.to%2Ffsuaget%2FY2VkNTFjOTNkN2UzMDk5NmIyMzljMDBmOGZlZWFmZmJmc3RvfDE2MDQyMDI5MzN8MTAwMDB8MHwwfHw3MDU4MDIzZGEzNDQ4NDI5MTZhN2RiNGI4ZGYxMWNlZHwxfDE0Njg3NTM3NTF8dmlkZW8%2C%2FThe.Walking.Dead.S06E01.1080p.HDTV.FOX+HD.ts`. Это не понимает даже Chrome